# iOS: Extract cover art from m4v

Tags: ios, uiimage, m4v

I have an m4v video file with cover art in an iOS app. Is it possible to get a UIImage * to the file's cover art image? I am able to get an NSString * to the video file, but am unsure on how to get a pointer to its cover art. I imagine it is somehow embedded in the file...

Comment: Is this an m4v from the user's iTunes library, or is it an m4v loaded from elsewhere in the file system?

Comment: Let's consider both scenarios.

Comment: Using the itunes library (Assuming you have an MPMediaItem for the content), it's pretty straight forward:


    MPMediaItem *currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
    UIImage *artworkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noArtworkImage.png"];
    MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [currentItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
 
    if (artwork) {
        artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (200, 200)];
    }
 
    [artworkImageView setImage:artworkImage];